# Haskell mapping function to list

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell and I have the following problem. I have to create a list of numbers [f1, f2, f3...] where `fi x = x ^ i`.  Then I have to create a function that applies the `fi` to a list of numbers. For example if I have a list `lis = [4,5,6,7..]` the output would be `[4^1, 5^2,6^3, 7^4...]`. This is what I have written so far :

```
powers x= [x^y |y<-[1,2,3,4]]
```

`list = [1,2,3,4]`

```
match :: (x -> xs) -> [x] -> [xs]
match f [] = []
match f (x:xs) = (f x) : ( match f xs )
```

So if I put the list = [1,2,3] the output is [1,1,1,1][2,4,8,16],[3,9,27,81] instead of [1,4,27]

Can you please tell me what is wrong and point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first issue is that `powers` is of type `Int -> [Int]`.  What you really want, I think, is something of type `[Int -> Int]` -- a list of `Int -> Int` functions instead of a function that takes an `Int` and returns a list of `Int`.  If you define `powers` like so:

```
powers = [(^y) | y <- [1..4]]
```

you can use `zipWith` to apply each power to its corresponding element in the list, like so:

```
zipWith ($) powers [1,2,3] -- returns [1,4,27]
```

The `($)` applies its left (first) argument to its right (second) argument.

Note that using `powers` as defined here will limit the length of the returned list to 4.  If you want to be able to use arbitrary length lists, you want to make `powers` an infinite list, like so:

```
powers = [(^y) | y <- [1..]]
```

Of course, as dave4420 points out, a simpler technique is to simply use

```
zipWith (^) [1,2,3] [1..] -- returns [1,4,27]
```

Comment: Heh -- that's what I get for imitating the OP's design

Answer (score 3):

Your `match` is the standard function [`map`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3amap) by another name. You need to use [`zipWith`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3azipWith) instead (which you can think of as mapping over two lists side-by-side).

Is this homework?

Comment: no it's not homework. i was searching for excercises in haskell and i found it and i thought i could give it a try since i am trying to learn haskell. i will try zipWith thank you .

Answer (score 1):

You are currently creating a list for every input value.
What you need to do is recursively compute the appropriate
power for each input value, like this:

```
match f [] = []
match f (x:xs) y = (f x y) : (match f xs y+1)
```

Then, you can call this as `match pow [1, 2, 3] 1`.
This is equivalent to using [zipWith](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/zipWith_f.html) and providing the desired function (`pow`), your input list (`[1, 2, 3]`) and the exponent list (a lazy one to infinity list) as arguments.